# How to send form values to php using javascript without reloading the page

Tags: php, html

I want to make a form in which an user enters a name to create a new record and want check simultaneously, if the record exists or not,  so the user can't insert 2 records with same name (but this is not primary key ) .
i am using following code right now but this reload page every time i need to check for value entered

```
    <html>
    <?php    
     require_once('../php/classes/class.add_album.php');
     $file_name='';
     $file_not_found="NULL";
     if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
          $file_name = test_input($_POST["file_name"]);
          echo $file_name; //for testing
          //make new object
          $objfile = new add_album();   
          //call object methid with post method value we got and save result in result 
          $file_not_found=$objfile->find_album($file_name);
          echo $file_not_found; //for testing

     }
    function test_input($data) {
       $data = trim($data);
       $data = stripslashes($data);
       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
    }
    if($file_not_found){
        echo '<form>';
        echo '<label>File Name </label>';
        echo '<input type="text" value='.$file_not_found.' >';

    }  else {
        echo '<form method="POST" action="temp.php">';
        echo '<label>File Name</label>';
        echo "<input type=text  name='file_name' placeholder='New file name plz'  >";
        echo"<input type=submit  name=submit value=submit>";

    }
    ?>        
    </form>
```

`

Comment: Sounds like a fun project! Let us know if you get stuck

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us your current code and tell us the problems you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow javascript ajax and same php file as above that i had mentioned.

Refere this link for ajax http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

```
    function validateUser()
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){ 

                 //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
               // do somting here..
               document.getElementById("captcha_validation").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }

}
  xmlhttp.open("POST","yourfile.php",true);

  xmlhttp.send("username=abc&password=xyz");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

user ajax to send form data to class .

Below is ajax function

```
$.ajax({
    url  :"yourfile.php",
    type :"POST",                   
    data    :$("#formid").serialize(),
    success : function(response)
   {
     // do someting here.
   }
```

Your PHP File (yourfile.php)

```
$obj = new db();
$yourdata = $_POST;
$res = $obj->validateUser($yourdata) ;
```

Comment: Need to mention that this is using [jquery](http://jquery.org), otherwise a newbee gets puzzled on the `$`

Comment: i am considering ajax but i dont want to use any lib. with ajax can you please tell me ajax code without using lib.